# Как производить запись звука в byte array на c# при помощи winmm.dll

Tags: c#, record

Необходимо снимать звук с микрофона и помещать его в байт массив, как такое организовать?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Посмотрите исходники [.NET Voice Recorder](http://voicerecorder.codeplex.com/) на основе [NAudio](http://naudio.codeplex.com/).

Сначала перечисляете устройства:

```
int waveInDevices = WaveIn.DeviceCount;
for (int waveInDevice = 0; waveInDevice < waveInDevices; waveInDevice++)
{
    WaveInCapabilities deviceInfo = WaveIn.GetCapabilities(waveInDevice);
    Console.WriteLine("Device {0}: {1}, {2} channels", 
        waveInDevice, deviceInfo.ProductName, deviceInfo.Channels);
}
```

Потом запускаете запись на одном из устройств:

```
WaveIn waveIn = new WaveIn();
waveIn.DeviceNumber = selectedDevice;
waveIn.DataAvailable += waveIn_DataAvailable;
int sampleRate = 8000; // 8 kHz
int channels = 1; // mono
waveIn.WaveFormat = new WaveFormat(sampleRate, channels);
waveIn.StartRecording();
```

И обрабатываете то, что пришло в waveIn_DataAvailable:

```
void waveIn_DataAvailable(object sender, WaveInEventArgs e)
{
    for (int index = 0; index < e.BytesRecorded; index += 2)
    {
        //
    }
}
```

Подробности работы расписаны в [этой статье на channel9](https://channel9.msdn.com/coding4fun/articles/NET-Voice-Recorder).